Convergence of integral over sequence of functions
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions converging uniformly to some $f$. If I can show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^\infty f_n(x)dx=I$$ exists, does it follow that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^nf_n(x)dx=I?$$ Or do I have to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_n^\infty f_n(x)dx=0?$$

What is $I$? Is it $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x),dx$? Also, is the convergence uniform on $[0,\infty)$ or on compact subsets?

Suppose $f_n$ is zero on both $[0,n]$ and $[2n,\infty)$ and that $f_n$ is $1/n$ on $(n,2n)$. Then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f_n=1$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{n}f_n=0.$
